# Sharepoint : JSscript from one page to another

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I'm developing a Sharepoint site with a  that make scroll horizontally a text :

[marquee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBpe0.png)

The text scroll into the yellow tape.

I want to edit the text that is scrolling from an another page with a textarea and a validate button :

[EditForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vakgh.png)

I have made the following script (one try among many...) :

```
$(function(){
    $('#btValider').click(function(){
        //var newMsg = document.getElementById("textarea").value; 
        newWindow = window.open("http://portail-wilointec/dev/th/SitePages/Accueil.aspx");
        var newMsg = window.opener.document.getElementById("textarea").value;
        newWindow.document.getElementById("msg").text(newMsg);
    
    });
```

});

The "marquee page" opens well, but the marquee value, which has the id="msg", is not edit.

I have also try to get the value of the textarea before opening the "marquee page", but it doesn't work yet.

Could someone help me please ?

Comment: Seems that "getElementById("msg").text(newMsg)" comes from jquery not origin JS? Shall we use "getElementById("msg").value=XXX;" ?

Comment: It doesn't work anymore. I use the jquery library so, the two methods have to work...